# Split string by newline and space in Bourne shell

Tags: shell, sh

I'm currently using the following to split a file into words - Is there some quicker way?

```
while read -r line
do
    for word in $line
    do
        words="${words}\n${word}"
    done
done
```

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Is there a reason you removed the 'bash' tag? I realize bash is different than sh, but given that there are 2500 tagged questions in the former and a whopping 5 in the latter, it would seem to me to be more useful to have both tags. All of the answers so far would apply to both shells.

Comment: The "shell" tag does the job of being directly applicable and achieving visibility. You asked about the Bourne shell in your title. I could have given a Bash-specific answer based on your tag and you wouldn't have been able to use it with some non-Bash shells. Note that if you had used "bourne" instead of "bourne-shell" there is an even whoppier 27 questions tagged with that. Some of those probably don't overlap, but most or all should. If they did, one tag could be eliminated reducing site tag clutter and improving visibility for both (even if only slightly).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about using [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29)?

```
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < myfile.txt
```

The `-s` squeezes multiple whitespace characters into one.

Comment: +1 for this solution. One minor detail: Use \\n, "\n" or '\n' instead of the unquoted \n

Answer (score 2):

```
xargs -n 1  echo <myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is slower than the others.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' file.txt
```